# Сделал калькулятор на php+jquery(ajax), но при вызове более двух калькуляторов с помощью shortcode ломается вёрстка всего сайта. Что делать?

Tags: php, ajax, калькулятор

Приветствую! 
Разработал плагин для WordPress калькулятор-конструктор.
Плагин разработан по MVC, почти не использую api WordPress. 
Калькулятор в записи выводится с помощью shortcode.

Проблема: при выводе в рубрике более одной записи с shortcode калькулятора, ломается вывод и верстка страницы category, пропадают записи после второй записи с калькулятором, пропадает или вовсе не выводится футер и имя категории в заголовке над записями категории! А кроме того не открывается вторая запись со вторым калькулятором!

Страница сайта, где присутствуют все баги [http://www.promolab.kz/category/стикеры-и-пломбы/#50](http://www.promolab.kz/category/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D1%8B/#50)
Страница сайта как должна выглядеть с нужными калькуляторами в записях, только их там нет, потому что с ними появляются баги [http://www.promolab.kz/category/полиграфия-большая](http://www.promolab.kz/category/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F)...

Ссылка на плагин калькулятора www.dropbox.com/s/n7t3kpqhe5nsxsc/calc-ord...

Может кто сталкивался или может дать совет, или помочь напрямую!

Comment: Ссылка на плагин не кликабельна. И залейте код на гит, а то ведь не удобно..

Comment: Сделайте запрет второго калькулятора (второго клика по ссылке)